# Spacy phrasematcher adding patterns with same match id

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I am using spacy's PhraseMatcher to identify drug names in user comments. I am pre-loading the names from a big file when the application server starts but don't want to do this at every document process because this takes a while.
While processing new documents, I want to add new drugs identified to the phrasematcher so that it identifies the new names. However, spacy won't accept new drugs with the same match_id. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# Global preload when application server starts
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
nlp = spacy.blank("en")

drug_list = []  # file import with 15k drug names
phrasematcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr='LOWER')
phrasematcher.add('drug', [nlp(itm) for itm in drug_list])
# The above process takes about couple of seconds to load so this process cannot run everytime

# Post process new documents
phrasematcher.add('drug', [nlp(itm) for itm in ['new drug 1', 'new drug 2']])
```

I get the below error.

```
span = Span(doc_pm, start, end, label=match_id)
File "span.pyx", line 118, in spacy.tokens.span.Span.__cinit__
ValueError: [E084] Error assigning label ID 16065740214838660377 to span: not in StringStore.
```

When I use match_id to find the hash and then use it, I get a different error.

```
phrasematcher.add(phrasematcher.vocab.strings['drug'], [nlp(itm) for itm in ['new drug 1', 'new drug 2']])
```

Error:

```
File "phrasematcher.pyx", line 222, in spacy.matcher.phrasematcher.PhraseMatcher.add
TypeError: an integer is required
```

> ```
> Spacy 2.2 
> Ubuntu 16 
> Python 3.6
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that `doc_pm` has not been processed with the same `nlp` pipeline that was used to create the `PhraseMatcher` so they don't have access to the same underlying `StringStore`. Check whether `doc_pm.vocab == phrasematcher.vocab`. If they are not the same, that's what's causing the `StringStore` error with `Span`.

The most straightforward solution is to use the same `nlp` pipeline consistently throughout so you only have one vocab for all components. If that's not feasible for some reason, it should also work to explicitly look up the label in the `PhraseMatcher` vocab:

```
span = Span(doc_pm, start, end, label=phrasematcher.vocab.strings[match_id])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I took some hint from maintaining a pipeline and I realized that I can solve my problem using EntityRuler.

Comment: Thanks it helped me to solve the problem where I was trying to load different based models for spancat and phrase matcher respectively